User registation failure in sophos xgs126 firewall
I am trying to create a ssl vpn connection through my office sophos firewall and in order to do that, I have to add a group to the ssl vpn policy. And that is only logical when I am able to add user to that group but alas, I can not register or create a new user. This is the error I encounter when trying to add a user using the sophos web admin portal. I am here providing an image of the error message that appears
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HuZlUIeNP4jeDyTnpbNblEgwj7vxeo0/view?usp=sharing
Things to keep in mid, the firewall was configured while being connected to the internet and there is no firewall rule preventing to create a user.
